# How to get sub attribute value using cheerio in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I am using cheerio library for data scraping. I am trying to get value of tag using below

```
var sparkLine = $(this)
  .find("td")
  .eq(7).text;
```

HTML

```
<td><a href="/currencies/bitcoin/#charts"><img class="sparkline" alt="sparkline" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/1.png"></a></td>
```

It returns undefined as there is no value of td tag and its child tag. Does anyone know how to get img src value here ?

It works well for below HTML

```
var sparkLine = $(this)
  .find("td")
  .eq(6).text;
```

HTML

```
<td class="no-wrap percent-24h  negative_change text-right" data-usd="-4.85" data-btc="0.00" >-4.85%</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Applying this code to the two TD tags on your question:**

```
    $('td', htmlCode)
        .each(function (counter, elem) {
            console.log(`#${counter}`);
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
```

**First tag:**

```
<td>
   <a href="/currencies/bitcoin/#charts">
     <img class="sparkline"
          alt="sparkline" 
          src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/1.png">
   </a>
</td>

// Returns:
#0
<a href="/currencies/bitcoin/#charts">
  <img class="sparkline"
         alt="sparkline" 
         src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/1.png">
</a>
```

** 2. Second tag:**

```
<td class="no-wrap percent-24h negative_change text-right"
    data-usd="-4.85"
    data-btc="0.00" >
    -4.85%
</td>

// Returns:
#0
-4.85%
```